# Applying formula for each column

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am learning how to automate a weekly sales report where my main sheet uses VLOOKUP to reference sales from another sheet. The headers are through Week 1 to the current week. How do I apply the formula for each column until the last one?

Here I have recorded a macro from inserting one of the formulas to the first column.

```
Sub Macrotesting()
'
' Macrotesting Macro
'

'
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Internal ID]],sales[#All],3,FALSE),0)"
    Range("L3").Select
    Range("CL[Week 1]").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CL[@[Internal ID]],sales[#All],3,FALSE),0)"
End Sub
```

I am lost on how to iterate through every column where sales for week 1 are in from the other table column 3 and week 2 are in column 4 and so on.

Comment: I don't know if you need VBA if your macro only does that. Just use the VLOOKUP formula along with MATCH for the column, searching for the header in de data sheet will give you back the column number to fit on every column of your  main sheet.

Comment: @Damian This is one part of my automation where I would need to apply calculations after. The purpose of using VBA is to have the whole report automated instead of manually entering each formula to each column

Comment: You just enter the formula on the first column and drag it to the others. Search on How to use VLOOKUP with MATCH, and try it, once it works record the macro and you will have the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to manipulate the formula and loop through a set of numbers, you could do the following:

```
For wknum = 1 To thiswknum

    Range("CL[Week " & wknum & "]").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CL[@[Internal ID]],sales[#All]," & wknum + 2 & ",FALSE),0)"

Next
```

Obviously, you'll need to detect / set `thiswknum` somehow, I'll leave that to you.